# PHP: Reading a string within placeholder

Tags: php, string

I am really confused how to word this question. I need to take some portion of string that enclosed in square bracket.
Please see the example

Re: [115] VFA 1 von 04/11/2012 bis 04/12/2012 mit-1221

This is somebody sending as subject of mail. I need to retrieve the   number 115 from the square bracket . If there are more than square bracket came , position of this will be first at any point

How could I fix that.

**EDIT**

I wish could I've get all instances of [] in the string 
Re: [115] [12] VFA 1 von 04/11/2012 bis 04/12/2012 mit-1221

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php):

```
preg_match_all('/\[(\w+)\]/', $str, $matches);
$square_brackets = $matches[1]; // array of: "115", "12"
```

Comment: Added thinking, If I have once more [] after first one , it will not worth it

Comment: @duke: Can you include this other example in your question, along with the data you wish to extract?

Answer (score 1):

> This is somebody sending as subject of mail. I need to retrieve the number 115 from the square bracket . If there are more than square bracket came , position of this will be first at any point

If it's always numeric, and always the first to be encased in brackets:

```
<?php
$line = 'Re: [115]VFA 1 von 04/11/2012 bis 04/12/2012 mit-1221';

if( preg_match( '~\[(\d+)\]~', $line, $matches ) !== 0 ) {
    $number = array_shift( $matches );
}
else { // no match.
}
```